# Bluetooth dongle with Realtek RTL8821CU chipset works, but not on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, 22.04, bluetooth

My system recognizes [my dongle](https://www.hardkernel.com/shop/wifi-module-5bk/) as supporting Bluetooth, but I cannot actually use the thing in any of the Bluetooth control interfaces (`bluetoothctl`, `btmgmt`, the graphical Bluetooth settings, etc.).

I tested the device on a Windows machine, and it worked there but not when I put it back into my Ubuntu machine.

Among the error messages and conditions I get:

```
$ sudo btmgmt
# power on
Set Powered for hci0 failed with status 0x03 (Failed)
```

```
$ sudo bluetoothctl
# list
[no output]
# show
No default controller available
```

The dongle supports both Bluetooth and Wi-Fi, and the company says they are supposed to work simultaneously. The Wi-Fi on the dongle works on Ubuntu.

### System information

```
$ uname --all
Linux odroid 4.9.337-31 […] aarch64 GNU/Linux

$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS \n \l

$ bluetoothctl --version
5.64

$ lsusb
[other devices]
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:c820 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11ac NIC
[other devices]

$ hciconfig -a
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00  ACL MTU: 0:0  SCO MTU: 0:0
    DOWN 
    RX bytes:917 acl:0 sco:0 events:130 errors:0
    TX bytes:33030 acl:0 sco:0 commands:131 errors:0
    Features: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
    Packet type: DM1 DH1 HV1 
    Link policy: 
    Link mode: PERIPHERAL ACCEPT

$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
[other modules]
btusb                  45056  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                24576  1 btusb
8821cu               2256896  0
bluetooth             479232  8 btrtl,btintel,bnep,btbcm,btusb
[other modules]
```

I also have [the result of `lsusb -v`](https://pastebin.com/z76TADDN) in case it helps.

### Logs

When I run `btmon` and start `bluetoothd` manually, this is what I get from `btmon` (abridged):

```
= New Index: 00:00:00:00:00:00 (Primary,USB,hci0)
= bluetoothd: Bluetooth daemon 5.64
@ MGMT Open: bluetoothd (privileged) version 1.14
= bluetoothd: Starting SDP server
@ MGMT Command: Read Management Version Information (0x0001) plen 0
@ MGMT Event: Command Complete (0x0001) plen 6
      Read Management Version Information (0x0001) plen 3
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Version: 1.14

[a few other successful commands and events]

@ MGMT Command: Remove Advertisement Monitor (0x0053) plen 2
        Handle: 0
@ MGMT Event: Command Status (0x0002) plen 3
      Remove Advertisement Monitor (0x0053)
        Status: Unknown Command (0x01)
= bluetoothd: src/adapter.c:reset_adv_monitors_complete() Failed to reset Adv Monitors: Unknown Command (0x01)
```

Those last two lines get printed in red. Also note the mac address on the first line. The monitor continues:

```
@ MGMT Command: Read Controller Information (0x0004) plen 0
@ MGMT Event: Command Complete (0x0001) plen 283
      Read Controller Information (0x0004) plen 280
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00 (OUI 00-00-00)
        Version: Bluetooth 4.2 (0x08)
        Manufacturer: Realtek Semiconductor Corporation (93)
        Supported settings: 0x000010bf
          Powered
          Connectable
          Fast Connectable
          Discoverable
          Bondable
          Link Security
          BR/EDR
          Debug Keys
        Current settings: 0x00000080
          BR/EDR
        Class: 0x000000
          Major class: Miscellaneous
          Minor class: 0x00
        Name: 
        Short name: 
= bluetoothd: No Bluetooth address for index 0
```

That last line also gets printed in red.

I also have [the output from `bluetoothd -n -d`](https://pastebin.com/1Y0qUv5x).

If I try to run `sudo hciconfig hci0 up`, I get this:

```
Can't init device hci0: Cannot assign requested address (99)
```

Let me know if I am missing any pertinent logs or system information.

---

### Edits

```
$ cat etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jammy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS"
```

I know that the problem is not with the Bluetooth devices to which I am trying to connect because:

1. I can't even initiate a `bluetoothctl` session controlling the dongle, and
2. When I plug the dongle into a Windows machine, it works and connects to the devices in question.

I asked [AmeriDroid](https://ameridroid.com), the product distributor, for help. The extent of the help they provided was telling me the device should work and deferred to [a relevant post](https://forum.odroid.com/viewtopic.php?p=364703#p364703) on the ODROID forum.

That forum post does not include any tips that have yielded results for me, and I have posted there as well asking for help.

[Hardkernel](https://www.hardkernel.com/), the product manufacturer, does not provide technical services, according to [their contact page](https://www.hardkernel.com/contact-us/), and links to the same forum AmeriDroid gave me.

Comment: What result for `cat /etc/lsb-release`

Comment: It looks like you're using HardKernel's ODROID kernel on their hardware, with their dongle, did you ask them how to get it working?